# MacOSX : Terminal App Issue : malloc: *** error for object 0x7ff213225110: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: macos, terminal.app, xcode

[image: ScreenShotofError]

[image: OsDetailInfo]

I need help with this issue shown in the picture above.

I have even restored with time machine to earlier time but still the same. I think or believe related with Xcode.

> malloc: error for object 0x7ff213225110: pointer being freed was
>   not allocated

Please explain/or teach us what is the logic behind this error.

Comment: Also tried fixing permissions thing to If anyone suggests

Comment: Also created another user profile and tried under didn't help

Comment: Boot in Safe mode didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Decided to perform **clean installation** of mac sierra, it was really easy and basic step. Took me 15 min to have fresh sierra osx.
**Referred to** : https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/macos-sierra-clean-install/

On Another Mac Laptop :

Opened Disk Utility and formatted my 128gb usb disk with defaults (Untitled - default name after format usb disk)
Ran this command on terminal with admin(sudo) privileges:

sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/**Untitled** --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app --nointeraction

This created bootable usb with sierra in it already. Then plugged into my mac laptop, pressed option when comes up.

I had time machine backups earlier, so could restore my stuff.

**Also this fresh installation provided me another solution/clearance :**
My mac model has 16gb memory that soldered to motherboard and during hardware check I get memory error, due to this error I am no longer able to update my OSx through internet because it runs hardware check before it installs. When I followed fresh install through usb it worked without issues, only thing is to create that usb I had to use another mac laptop.